# Encoding and Decoding special characters (Latin-1)

Tags: python-3.x, decode, python-unicode, unicode-string

I´m trying to clean some strange unicode characters after my HTML parsing, but is still not converting these unicodes.

Original text:

```
raw = 'If further information is needed, donÂ´t hesitate to contact us. Kind regards, JosÃ© Ramirez.'
```

After encoding & decoding:

```
text = str(raw.encode().decode('unicode_escape'))
```

Current output:

```
'If further information is needed, donÃ\x82Â´t hesitate to contact us. Kind regards, JosÃ\x83Â© Ramirez'
```

Desired output:

```
'If further information is needed, don´t hesitate to contact us. Kind regards, José Ramirez'
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it the wrong way around. The effect of your `raw.encode().decode('unicode_escape')` is the same as `raw.encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1')`. What you really want:

```
>>> raw.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
'If further information is needed, don´t hesitate to contact us. Kind regards, José Ramirez.'
```

Your string came from someone taking UTF-8 encoded text, but assuming it is Latin-1.

If you have many different variants of *Mojibake* (the incorrect decoding of text, resulting in gibberish), the [`ftfy`](https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) packages can help:

```
>>> import ftfy
>>> ftfy.fix_text('If further information is needed, donÂ´t hesitate to contact us. Kind regards, JosÃ© Ramirez.')
'If further information is needed, don´t hesitate to contact us. Kind regards, José Ramirez.'
```